# Multiple encoding of videos using AviSynth and X264 from a bat file

Tags: batch-file, video, batch-processing, x264, avisynth

at the moment i am encoding my videos (vhs restoration) using avisynth and x264 via dragging an .avs file onto a bat file.

This is working great, but my problem (well not really a problem, more of an efficiency issue) is that i have to manually keep dragging my avs files onto the bat to start the process. Would it be possible to have the bat file convert a whole directory of videos (maybe 20 or so) one after the other in an automated way?

The .avs file is always the same for each video except the AviSource() line.

I know i can loop the .bat for the number of videos present, but how do i load in the .avs file having a variable AviSource()?

How could i achieve this, or is it not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: See [GetSystemEnv](http://www.avisynth.nl/users/stickboy/GetSystemEnv.zip) plugin for avisynth.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=162280

Comment: @wOxxOm Neat, somehow I don't think that I ever considered that as a use case for GetSystemEnv. (I wrote GetSystemEnv so long ago that I don't remember my motivation for it, so maybe I just forgot...)